# A problem on generators and Hensel lifting

Tags: nt.number-theory

Say $\ell^2-\ell-\delta\equiv0\bmod p$ is a polynomial $x^2-x-\delta$ with root $\ell$ and we lift to $\ell'^2-\ell'-\delta\equiv0\bmod p^2$ by Hensel lifting my question is following: if $g^y\equiv \ell^2\bmod p$ held at a generator $g$ then is there an explicit generator $g'$, which can be found in polynomial time, for which $$g'^y\equiv\ell'^2\bmod p^2$$ holds true?

Comment: It looks like a question about lifting generators, while polynomials are irrelevant. Also, $x$ in the power of $g$ has nothing to do with $x$ in the polynomial.

Comment: How to connect $\ell$ and $\ell'$ without Hensel which needs a polynomial?

Comment: Surely you just need to Hensel lift the equation $z^y - \ell'^2 = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $g'=g(1+ap)$ so that
$$g'^y\equiv g^y(1 + pya)\pmod{p^2}.$$
It follows that we can take
$$a = \frac{(\ell^2/g^{y}\bmod p^2)-1}{py},$$
which can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: Is the computation of a over mod p^2? You are dividing by p. Is it $a \equiv \frac{\big(\frac{\ell'^2}{g^{y}}\bmod p^2\big)-1}{py}\bmod p^2$ as $\ell'$ is over $\bmod p^2$?

Comment: What's in the parentheses is computed modulo $p^2$, but division by $p$ then reduces the modulus and results in a residue mod $p$. So, $a$ is defined modulo $p$.